# Sending Fax using SMTPClient?

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, fax

We have a exchangeserver configured to send the attachment of a email as fax if the the "to-address-field" is in the format [fax:user/company@faxnumber] (used internally). It works when I send manually from Outlook. But how can send an email with to-address as above using Smtpclient?

Is it possible to suppress the emailaddress validation? at the moment i get this error:
"System.FormatException : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through the SmtpClient. If fax=asdfasdf is wanted then going through interop.outlook.dll is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that it's not possible. However, at least in .Net 4.0 (which is less restrictive than earlier versions), everything except the `:` is fine though. Maybe you could get the admins to change the SMTP server to support other characters than `:` after the string `fax`?

For example, maybe you could use `fax=` instead.

Comment: Yes, the usual format is something like "FAX=12125551212@mydomain.com"

Comment: It fails even with "=" instead of ":".
Stacktrace:
at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ReadCfwsAndThrowIfIncomplete(String data, Int32 index)
at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseDomain(String data, Int32& index)
at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses, Int32& index)
at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseMultipleAddresses(String data)
at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection.ParseValue(String addresses)

Comment: @ThorHalvor: Are you using .Net 4.0? Remember that it's less restrictive than earlier version (though I've only tried to create a `MailMessage` with a `MailAddress` that contains a `=`, I've not tried to actually send it so it might fall over at a later stage).

Comment: Yes i use 4.0. And yes, it failes in an later stage given in stacktrace above. currently im trying withoug []brackets and = instead of :...

Comment: @ThorHalvor: Didn't realise that the brackets were part of the address. Without that it seems ok with the = in .Net 4.0 for me.